# Creating timed markers on a leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, visualization, mapbox

I have a leaflet project where I am delivering a continuous stream of 'coordinates' via WebSockets to the client browser. I need to be able to display markers corresponding to those locations for a set period of time (something like 1 or 2 seconds) and then remove them (to make room for more locations).

Can anyone help me out or point me in the direction of resources wherein I could find some help?

Thanks!

Edit : Why the downvote? Its a legitimate and common question and one without a lot of solutions online.

Comment: You probably got downvotes because you didn't make the right question. If you ask, literally, «Can anyone help me?» then the answer is gonna be «yes», [and you shouldn't be surprised about that](http://www.strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html).

Comment: Why would you isolate one sentence of my question and think that was the problem. Do you see the rest of it about the timed markers and leaflet?? When someone asks you if you can pass the butter at the breakfast table, they are not questioning your ability to pick and move things, they actually want the butter. Its just a polite way to ask for help.

Comment: **Yes**, I see what the rest of the question is about. But this is not a breakfast table, and the rules of politeness of breakfast tables don't apply here. A lot of people here (me included) think that instead it's more polite to show that you have done as much research on your own as possible. Quoting [ESR's "How to ask questions the smart way"](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#explicit): «it is useful to frame your question to minimize the time commitment required for an expert to field it».

Comment: I mentioned what the question was about in my title ('Creating timed markers'). Then I mentioned in the description what I wanted to do more. I mentioned what the data was, where I was getting it and how long I wanted the marker to stay on the map. I then decided to write one line "Can anyone help me out...". You have decided to take issue with this one line with which I ended the question. My question was fine. I appreciate you going so much out of your way to give it, but I reject your advice.

Comment: Calm down guys! Here is a post about the "question-problem": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question I think it's clear that Vib wants some help about his problem, and I think I understood what he wanted. But @IvanSanchez is also right, and like the post says, good questions can be searched easier. (sorry if the english isn't that good)

Comment: Fair enough :) Thanks for your help. I will designate your answer as the solution in an hour or so

Comment: Just an idea: you could stick a timestamp on each marker (`Date.now()` value) on a ttl property and run a check every 2 seconds for all markers. All markers with `ttl < Date.now() - 2000` will be removed.

Comment: Would be possible, but I think my solution is more perfomant, because in your case, it could be possible that each 2 seconds it is iterated over all markers. If the amount of markers is very high, it will become slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code from the documentation (http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layer):

```
var layer = L.Marker(latLng).addTo(map);
layer.addTo(map);
layer.remove();
```

So in order to remove it after 2 seconds, I think you could try this one:

```
var layer = L.Marker(latLng).addTo(map);
layer.addTo(map);

setTimeout(function() {
    layer.remove();
}, 2000);
```

[Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/NZoZKugfMLdwJjGa4gCx/)

Comment: Would this cause the entire map to timeout? I want to be able to add and remove (older) markers in the 2 second window that each marker is alive. I was hoping for something like a ttl (time to live) setting for the marker but I dont think thats a thing.

Comment: I have added an example. The map should work while the timeout, because the function inside of the setTimeout call will be executed asynchronusly. But the setting in the marker would be a nice feature!